# Why is _stprintf_s overwriting other variables but _stprintf is not?

Tags: c++, winapi, printf, malloc

I'm using visual studio for win32 programming class. I have a global array of string declared as `TCHAR **bufTh` allocated in memory like

```
bufTh = (TCHAR**)malloc(nOfTh*sizeof(TCHAR*));
for (i = 0; i < nOfTh; i++)
    bufTh[i] = (TCHAR*)malloc(BUF_LEN*sizeof(TCHAR));
```

then I have some threads, each of them writing on a different string in this array. I noticed that if i use `_stprintf_s(bufTh[iTh], BUF_LEN, _T("%s\\"), findData.cFileName);`, after this operation, some others global variables (in my case semaphores) are overwritten, while if I use `_stprintf` (without _s) everything goes well.

Why? Where am I going wrong?

I also tried as experiment to use an array of struct containing a string, like `typedef struct{TCHAR buf[BUF_LEN];} mystr_t;` and then allocate `bufTh = (mystr_t*)malloc(nOfTh*sizeof(mystr_t));`. In this case `_stprintf_s` is working as expected causing no problem.

EDIT: here is a mcve

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BUF_LEN _MAX_PATH+1

typedef struct{
    DWORD iTh;
} tdata_t;

TCHAR **bufTh;
PHANDLE sem;

//DWORD WINAPI rThread(LPVOID pThParam);

int _tmain(int argc, LPTSTR argv[]){
    DWORD   i, nOfTh;
    PHANDLE hthread;
    tdata_t *tdata;

    nOfTh = 1;

    // global array of buffers, one for each reading thread
    bufTh = (TCHAR**)malloc(nOfTh*sizeof(TCHAR*));
    for (i = 0; i < nOfTh; i++)
        bufTh[i] = (TCHAR*)malloc(BUF_LEN*sizeof(TCHAR)); 

    // array of thread data, to pass to threads
    tdata = (tdata_t*)malloc(nOfTh*sizeof(tdata_t));
    for (i = 0; i < nOfTh; i++){
        tdata[i].iTh = i;
    }

    // array of semaphores, one for each thread
    sem = (PHANDLE)malloc((nOfTh)*sizeof(HANDLE)); 
    for (i = 0; i < nOfTh; i++)
        sem[i] = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 1, NULL);

    // array of threads
    /*hthread = (PHANDLE)malloc(nOfTh*sizeof(HANDLE));
    for (i = 0; i < nOfTh; i++)
        hthread[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &rThread, (LPVOID)&tdata[i], 0, NULL);*/

    i = 0;
    // BREAKPOINT HERE
    _stprintf_s(bufTh[i], BUF_LEN, _T("%s\\"), _T("the string that I want to write there"));
    // BREAKPOINT HERE
    WaitForSingleObject(sem[i], INFINITE);



    //WaitForMultipleObjects(nOfTh, hthread, TRUE, INFINITE);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show more code please.

Comment: which part could be relevant? I think that what I showed is a minimum working example

Comment: You write "some other variables" ? Where are those variables located ? And your are writing about threads, maybe your code is simply not thread safe.

Comment: I get your point. The overwritten variables are the semaphores, which are declared as global. There's a wait on the thread's semaphore right after that sprintf_s, which in that case doesn't put the thread in wait mode because the semaphores have been messed up. Complete code is [here](http://pastebin.com/VcTJc2eh)

Comment: Why do you mention the wide char versions `swprintf_s` and `swprintf` in the title?

Comment: Please show an mcve here

Comment: typo, I'm using `_stprintf_s` and `_stprintf`but I was reading the documentation for the wide char version since I'm using `#define UNICODE`

Comment: It's quite possible there is nothing wrong with that statement, but altering it realigns the code / data so as to reveal or hide the damage done by a different bug.

Comment: I tried to make a mcve [here](http://pastebin.com/iuZANuNc)

Comment: You missed the part that demands an MVCE to be *minimal*. Also, off-site references aren't a good choice. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30479199/edit) your question, and include the MVCE here.

Comment: I compiled and ran your posted "minimal" code. I gave the names of two folders with identical contents (4 files each). The program prints the name of one file in each folder then terminates. It makes no different which of the two `_stprintf` lines are enabled, or whether the folders have different contents.

Comment: If this is a `C` (not `C++`) question sou shouldn't cast the `malloc` return value. If you use a C++ compiler you should use the `C++` tag.

Comment: ok, I got all your points. I did modify the question adding a mcve trying to stay as minimal as possible. For me is still possible to reproduce the error, which is that using `_stprintf_s` the thread do not wait at semaphore, while using  `_stprintf` it does

Comment: I ran the code on 2 different folders, each containing ~15 files. And I got a crash in the rThread function at line `bufTh[tdata->iTh][0] = '\0'. `tdata`pointed to a structure which was overwritten with the `0xfefefefe`pattern (freed memory). With `stprintf`I don't get the crash.

Comment: also in my runs semaphores are overwritten with value 0xfefefefe. I didn't know this is a pattern for freed memory

Comment: The memory patterns in the debug heap are listed at [Win32 Debug CRT Heap Internals](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html). If you run your code under a debugger, you'll see the callstack at the time where you trash memory. Get used to using a debugger.

Comment: I can't see why the argument I pass to the thread should be a wild pointer

Comment: And no, I just double checked, I see 0xfefefefe - not 0xfeeefeee, nor 0xFDFDFDFD.

Comment: @HansPassant I investigated on the wild pointer, and I believe that what is happening is not actually a wild pointer but instead the `_stprintf_s` overwriting that pointer. I updated the mvce removing the thread calling and I am still able to reproduce the error: `sem[0]` is changed to `0xfefefefe` after the `_stprintf_s` so it is impossible to wait on it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> also in my runs semaphores are overwritten with value 0xfefefefe

This is a "magic value", it is written by the safe CRT functions (like _stprintf_s) to help you debug mistakes in the buffer length you pass.  The debug build of these functions fill the entire buffer, using 0xfe as a padding value.

```
   _stprintf_s(bufTh[i], BUF_LEN, ...));
```

So what you *know* is that the buffer size of thBuf[0] is **not** in fact BUF_LEN.  In other words, the malloc() call is incorrect.

```
   #define BUF_LEN _MAX_PATH+1
```

This is an evil macro and causes your problem.  It expands to

```
   bufTh[i] = (TCHAR*)malloc(_MAX_PATH + 1*sizeof(TCHAR));
```

Not what you meant of course.  Fix:

```
   #define BUF_LEN (_MAX_PATH+1)
```

The extra parentheses are critical.  Otherwise a good reason to start using the `const` keyword.

Comment: I googled for  0xfefefefe but I did not find relevant result. Is there a reference where I can learn something more about these "magic values"? Thanks anyway

Comment: I just created a reference.  Well, only works if SO users vote it helpful.